# SEO for image handler

Tags: images, google-index, asp.net, handler

I have handler, which have URL like this `/imgrs.axd?w=300&file=2ce5a421-d71a-4dba-9d54-3103058e15b2.jpg`, where

- `w` is width for image
- `file` is filename

Server's answer:

```
Cache-Control   public
Content-Length  9788
Content-Type    image/jpeg
Date    Sun, 05 Jan 2014 10:24:41 GMT
Expires Sun, 12 Jan 2014 10:24:42 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
```

But Google doesn't want to append these images in its index base.
How can I improve accessibility these images for Google?

Comment: how long have has it been on these images? and are they unique?

Comment: Presumably this is not blocked by robots.txt? Perhaps a `Content-Disposition` header would help, that identifies the expected filename?

Comment: Where are you using these images?  The pages the images are in have to be crawlable and have enough Pagerank.

Comment: They is unique. I used these images 2-3 mounths in the main page and many other pages.

Comment: care to share the URL please?

Comment: http://rielter77.ru/imgrs.axd?w=800&file=f8b8b408-45d6-4bfe-87e1-d44e25a05728.jpg

Comment: Although you reference the images on the page using a "static" URL and presumably rewrite to your handler - you never reference the handler directly - which is good. In fact, you do already have many of these images indexed by Google, albeit the smaller ones which are referenced directly on the page. As Stephen suggests, I think the problem is more to do with the images being crawlable. The larger images displayed with the JavaScript image viewer do not appear to be indexed and these have exactly the same filename (but slightly different path) to the small thumbnails which are already indexed.

Answer (score 1):

When having using server side resizing I would recommend that you either create a URL rewrite or (since your are on the .NET platform) use a HTTP module (`System.Web.IHttpModule`) that handles image request.

The basic idea is that you can have your URLs like this in your HTML `/2ce5a421-d71a-4dba-9d54-3103058e15b2.jpg?w=300`, but actually serve a URL like this: `imgrs.axd?w=300&file=2ce5a421-d71a-4dba-9d54-3103058e15b2.jpg`

But for that to have decent effect on SEO, you should name your files to something meaningful - i.e. `sunny_beach.jpg` instead of `2ce5a421-d71a-4dba-9d54-3103058e15b2.jpg`.

Comment: Although it's not obvious in the question (there is a link in the comments), the URL mentioned would seem to be the served (rewritten ) URL, not the URL as it appears in the HTML document. The HTML already appears to contain more "regular-looking" image URLs of the form: `/images/flat/800/f8b8b408-45d6-4bfe-87e1-d44e25a05728.jpg` (although not descriptive, like you say.)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your site, I think your ranking issues have more to do with your watermarks than your URLs.   Google likes to rank "high quality images".   This generally means large, full color, clean images.

You have watermarks all over your images.   This is detectable by the Google algorithms and makes it much less likely for your images to show up in image search.

Comment: You are saying that watermarked images are detectable by Google algorithms but in this http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2009/11/pros-and-cons-of-watermarked-images.html post. Peter Linsley ( Product Manager of Image Search ) said that "The presence of a watermark doesn't itself cause an image to be ranked higher or lower. ".

Comment: Google detects quality via both algorithms and user feedback.    Your link seems to indicate that they don't have a specific watermank algorithm but that the usability signals of in your face watermarks can be used by Google to lower rankings.